# Returning Collection items and empty Arrays for Java

Tags: java, arrays

Can you help with findByTitle?

I want to return the movie with the given title or null if there is no movie in the library with that title. I added null at the end so that it would compile.

```
public Movie findMovieByTitle(String title)
{
  for(Movie movieToSearch : movies) {
      if (movieToSearch.equals(title)){
            return movieToSearch;
        }else{
            return null;
       } 
    } 
    return null; 
}
```

I need help with the remove movie method.

```
/**
 * removes movie based on title
 */
public void removeMovie(String title)
{  //fix this
    Iterator<Movie> it = movies.iterator();
    while(it.hasNext()) {
        Movie movie = it.next();
        if(movie.equals(title)) 
            movies.remove(movie);
    }

}
```

I seem to almost be there... but not quite. I want to return movies with the rating, not print them out.

For the else if statement, I just want to return an empty array. How can I do that?

```
public void getMoviesWithStarRating(int rating)
{   
    Iterator<Movie> it = movies.iterator();
    while(it.hasNext()) {
        Movie movie = it.next();
        if (movie.getStarRating() == rating) {
           //return movie;

            //Testing output:
           System.out.println("Movie: " + movie.getTitle() + "  Rating: " + movie.getStarRating());
        }
        else if (rating < 0 || rating > 4){
          //return empty array
          //test
           System.out.println("invalid entry");
        }
    }
}
```

printRatingReport()

{
//code

}

Lastly, I want to  Write a method called printRatingReport that prints the number of movies of each star rating
     Sample output:

```
       4-star movies: 2

       3-star movies: 1

       2-star movies: 0

       1-star movies: 0

       Unrated movies: 2
```

Answer (score 0):

You problably use wrong container. You might want to use `Map<String, Movie>` then just call `movie.get(title)`. This guarantees behaviour you ask for.

If you insist to use `List` use `indexOf(Object o)` method but first you need to override `equals()` and `hashCode()` for your movie.

**NOTICE:**
`movie` doesn't equal `title` AS `apple` doesn't equal `banana`.

Comment: I'm trying to match the parameter. how would I do that?

Comment: `movie.title.equals(title)` or `movie.getTitle().equals(title)` or `movie.equals(new Movie(title))//bad idea + you need to override equals`.

Comment: oh! yeah thanks for the reminder. I had something like movie.getTitle().equals(title)   but I guess I erase it. I have been writing a bunch of different things so many times. haha.

Comment: ok, my error was concurrent modification exception so i thought it was wrong. I though Iterator avoids that problem?

Comment: @wannabecoder did you use `ArrayList`? If yes, really fast but dirty solution is just to change it to `CopyOnWriteArrayList`, I am 80% positive that you may also use `Vector` but I rarely use it. Standard loop with index avoids this exception. For-each and while with iterator are essentialy the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I think there is something wrong with your `findMovieByTitle(String title)` method, and here is what I think it should be, if the method to get the **Movie** title is `getTitle()`:

```
public Movie findMovieByTitle(String title)
{
  for(Movie movieToSearch : movies) {
      if (movieToSearch.getTitle().equals(title)){
            return movieToSearch;      
      } 
  }
    return null; 
}
```

And the problem in your `getMoviesWithStarRating` is that it shouldn't return `void`, instead it should return a list of `Movie`, like `ArrayList<Movie>`.

Comment: can i get help with returning an empty array?  for   getMoviesWithStarRating   method